# Find a value from a range of cells in column over many sheets and return a "X" in next empty column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put a "X" or what ever in a the next empty column that I later can use `INDEX` and `INDERECT` (since the sheets are named the same as the range in column A in my main sheet) to look up for my main sheet. The "X" needs to be added in each of the sheets where the value is found.

The column in the sheets where the numbers I need to find the value is always in column A. In my main sheet the values are listed from `B2:B23`. The range varies in each sheet (from 400 to 5000 rows).

Is there a clever way of doing this that I haven't found still?

atm there are 80 sheets and the one main sheet

Code:

```
Sub Mark_cells_in_column()
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim I As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Search for a Value Or Values in a range
MyArr = Array("34-2472", "36-437", "36-4351", "36-4879", "36-4982", "36-4981" _
, "36-5715", "36-4983", "36-4984", "36-5125", "36-5126", "36-5257", "36-6139" _
, "38-7079-1", "38-7079-2", "44-1276", "31-8589", "31-8589-1", "31-8647", "36-6149" _
, "36-5770", "31-8590")

'Search Column or range
With Sheets("3").Range("A:A") 'cant get my head around how to get this to apply so it loops through every sheet except main sheet

    'clear the cells in the column to the right
    .Offset(0, 13).ClearContents

    For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

        'If you want to find a part of the rng.value then use xlPart
        'if you use LookIn:=xlValues it will also work with a
        'formula cell that evaluates to "values listed"

        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                'mark the cell in the column to the right if "Values listed" is found
                Rng.Offset(0, 13).Value = "X"
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next I
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: To answer your one question; Probably, but we don't know what you have found or tried.  SO is not a code for me site.  Please post what you have tried and possibly a screen shot of what you have and what you want, so we might help you better

Comment: @ScottCraner atm i haven't tried other then a loop, but its not working and there aint much point for me to post the code cause I know its rubbish. But I can keep at it. My first idea was to make a loop, but im stuck.

Comment: `loop` through column A.  Using the value in column A as your `sheet name` use `Find` to see `if` the values exist in Column A of the Sheet named, if the value is found place an "X: using `offset`.  Search on the keywords and try putting it together.  When you get stuck on a specific problem come back with the specific problem and we will help.

Comment: @ScottCraner ill add that to what im trying. thank you

Comment: "...aint much point for me to post the code cause I know its rubbish."  - Actually, that's a **good** reason to post it!  We're here to help with code that is working, but "gross".  It also shows us that you've tried something, and aren't just asking us to code stuff for you.  It will also give some insight in to how you're going about trying what you want to do.  Post the relevant code and we can see if we can help clean it up.  (It could explain too why you have some downvotes.  Read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when you can).

Comment: @BruceWayne i get what you say so I put the entire code in there. Just wanna post something I can get my head fully around. This is tested on one sheet with no result

Comment: Thanks! So is your main issue getting this to loop in all sheets *except* your main sheet?

Comment: @BruceWayne atm the macro aint showing any errors but I doesn't mark "X" in the column (could it be `xlValues`?), and yes, im stuck at the "loop through the sheets based on cells in column A in my main sheet"-problem ;)

Comment: figured I try to see if there was extra space inside the cells which there was, so now the macro works, finally, but im stuck on the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Sub Mark_cells_in_column()
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MyArr   As Variant
Dim Rng     As Range
Dim I       As Long

Dim mainWS As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set mainWS = Sheets("Main")  ' Change this to whatever the name of your Main WS is, that you DON'T want to run the macro on

'Search for a Value Or Values in a range
MyArr = Array("34-2472", "36-437", "36-4351", "36-4879", "36-4982", "36-4981" _
, "36-5715", "36-4983", "36-4984", "36-5125", "36-5126", "36-5257", "36-6139" _
, "38-7079-1", "38-7079-2", "44-1276", "31-8589", "31-8589-1", "31-8647", "36-6149" _
, "36-5770", "31-8590")

' Loop through Sheets
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> mainWS.Name Then
    With ws
        'Search Column or range
        With .Range("A:A")
            'clear the cells in the column to the right 13 columns (aka column N)
            .Offset(0, 13).ClearContents

            For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

                'If you want to find a part of the rng.value then use xlPart
                'if you use LookIn:=xlValues it will also work with a
                'formula cell that evaluates to "values listed"

                Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                                After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)

                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                    Do
                        'mark the cell in the column to the right if "Values listed" is found
                        Rng.Offset(0, 13).Value = "X" ' This marks it in 13 columns to the right where the value is found
                        Set Rng = .Columns("A:A").FindNext(Rng)
                    Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
                End If
            Next I
        End With ' Ends the .Range("A:A")
    End With ' ends the `with WS`
    End If
Next ws

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

The main thing seemed to be you were using the very last cell (`After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count)`) with `SearchDirection:=xlNext`.  ...there's no next cell, if you're at the end!  So, I changed that to `After:=.Cells(1,1)`.

Secondly, I added a loop to check the worksheets, and if it's "Main", skip it.  Edit as required.

Comment: theres a `End Sub` above the `End With 'ends the With WS'`.

Comment: other then that Im happy you could help me solve this Bruce

Comment: @krib - Ah, good catch (I copy/pasted and must have not selected all of the text).  I have updated it.

Comment: again thank a lot. Sorry for my bad start at the question

Comment: Thanks @findwindow :P

Comment: @findwindow - you keep mentioning this character, but I'm lost as to who you're talking about. ...